# Bash Script Unexpected End of File - new coder

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash, I'm just trying to pick in up in my free time. I'm writing a simple script that prints out the filename I supply as many times as there are characters in the filename, and then positive or negative based on the second argument. I'm getting an unexpected end of file error on this script, and I'm not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
NUMBER=$2

COUNT=0;
STR=${#FILENAME}

while ($COUNT < $STR){
echo $FILENAME
$COUNT++
}

if ($NUMBER < 0)
echo "Negative"
if ($NUMBER > 0)
echo "Positive"

exit
```

I'm executing with

```
./script1.sh hello 2
```

and I'm expecting the output to be

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
Positive
```

If anyone could shed some light as to what's going on with the error, that'd be great.

edit: forgot to add the second condition to add to the COUNT variable, and now I'm getting an error:

```
line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
line 9: `while ($COUNT < $STR){'
```

Comment: there are few errors here. I suggest you to use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get an explanation of each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are confusing Bash's syntax with some other language.

In Bash, `if`'s syntax (if not using `else`) is `if condition;then commands;fi`. Your code does not have `then` and `fi`. Also, the condition should be `(( $NUMBER > 0 ))`.

The syntax of `while` is `while condition;do commands;done`, and your code is also wrong.

Comment: So it would read if 
    ($NUMBER -lt 0)
    echo "Negative"
    fi

Comment: I'd say that "some other language" is C, or something in the C family.

Comment: Also, would be better to use a normal `for` loop: `for ((i=1; i<=${#name}; i++))` instead of keeping track of a counter.